# How can I install package of Latex use Texmarker

Tags: latex, texmaker

I 'm new to use Latex. I have installed ***MiKTex*** and ***Texmarker***. I opened my file ***"test.tex"***. Program need to install one package, I choose "yes". But after this , i still got error , file  ***"...sty"*** not found. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance!

P/S: I'm using Windows:)

Comment: Create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Miktex, so I cannot test the aswer. A quick search gives the aswer:

```
mpm --verbose --install X
```

You should type this inside a system console and X is the package you need. If the error is the same it means that the package is not in the Miktek repositories and you should install it manually. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/packages.html) on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed MikTex, it has a default setting of installing packages on the fly. This means that all you need to do is use the command
 `\usepackage{name-of-package}` 
at the beginning of your document. Be sure that this command comes before `\begin{document}`. If this doesn't work, you may want to check this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly) for further help.